# TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing, creating a hash Key for email activation

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create as hash_key for email activation but am getting the type error above. Any ideas how i can enforce encoding. Below is my code:

```
def user_created(sender, instance, created, *args, **Kwargs):
    user = instance

    if created:
        get_create_stripe(user)
        email_confirmed, email_is_created = EmailConfirmed.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        if email_is_created:
            short_hash = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random()).hexdigest())[:5]
            base, domain = str(user.email).split('@')
            activation_key = hashlib.sha1(short_hash+base).hexdigest()
            email_confirmed.activation_key = activation_key
            email_confirmed.save()
            email_confirmed.activate_user_email()

post_save.connect(user_created, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `bytes` to `hashlib.sha1()` method instead of `string`. To do it you can just use [`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) like this:

```
short_hash = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random()).encode()).hexdigest()[:5]
base, domain = str(user.email).split('@')
activation_key = hashlib.sha1((short_hash+base).encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: hi, i tried this and got error cant encode float, i guess since random.random returns floats. so i tried to encode after the conversion to string like this short_hash = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random()).encode().hexdigest())[:5] but still got attribute error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'

Comment: @Muhuri.JSON you missed `)` before . hexdigest(). Just copy code from answer. It should work.